# Android : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio. I tried to build an app and got the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2330Library'.
> Failed to create parent directory 'C:\Users\Prasang\Downloads\reelover\app\build' when creating directory 'C:\Users\Prasang\Downloads\reelover\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\23.3.0'

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.989 secs
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you try to run with `--info` or `--stacktrace` as suggested by Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try "Build --> Clean or Rebuild Project"?
Look through your .xml files if all your drawables are correct. If there is still a problem look trough all your drawable directorys that all endings are small like ".png  .jpg instead of .PNG  .JPG"

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hii, The "Rebuild Project" worked magically. I thought it was just with Eclipse that cleaning a project works.

Comment: @PrasangMisra Awesome, glad it helped